# Can MOQ Mock a Class

Tags: moq

is it legal to MOQ a class that does not inherit an interface like so:

```
var mockIActionService = new Mock<IActionService>();
var mockValidAgeRule = new Mock<ValidAgeRule>(mockIActionService.Object);
```

I inject the IService into ValidAgeRule which is just a simple class with one method called "Excute". My question is how to I verify that has been called. Whenever I try:

```
 mockValidAgeRule.Verify(x => x.Execute(app)); //Where App is a valid object
```

does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I think you forgot to include what happens when you try to call mockValidAgeRule.Verify().  I am assuming the test fails even though you are sure Execute has been called.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe you need to make your Execute method virtual.

My understanding is that Moq creates a subclass of your class in this case, and needs to override your method in order to keep track of whether it has been called.

Comment: ya I heeded to make it virtual